# Conflict between jquery and ajax

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax, updatepanel, igoogle

I use Igoogle component [inettuts](http://james.padolsey.com/demo/tut-inettuts-with-cookies/) and I have some links in the side of my web page if the user remove a block of data he can get it back i use `ajax` to achieve my goal as the following :

## My .aspx :

```
 <ul id="column2" class="column" runat="server">
            <asp:UpdatePanel ID="uppnl_2" runat="server">
                <Triggers>
                    <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="rlv_mainservices" 
                        EventName="ItemCommand" />
                </Triggers>
            </asp:UpdatePanel>
  <!-- ////////////////////////////////////////////////-->
```

---

## My .cs :

```
 protected void rlv_mainservices_ItemCommand(object sender, RadListViewCommandEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.CommandName == "GetDtails")
            {
                try
                {
                    int index = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument);
                    CreateBlockOfData("widget color-blue", 2, "aaa");
                }
                catch (Exception ee)
                {
                }
            }
        }
```

---

```
 protected void CreateBlockOfData(string widget_color, int column_par, string process_name)
        {
            HtmlGenericControl outer_li = new HtmlGenericControl("li");
            outer_li.Attributes.Add("class", widget_color);
            if (column_par == 1)
            {
                column1.Controls.Add(outer_li);
            }
            else if (column_par == 2)
            {
                uppnl_2.ContentTemplateContainer.Controls.Add(outer_li);

            }
            else if (column_par == 3)
            {
                column3.Controls.Add(outer_li);
            }
            else if (column_par == 4)
            {
                column4.Controls.Add(outer_li);
            }
           //The rest of code
        }
```

My problem is :when i click on the link (in my list view) the block of data created without(remove,edit,minimize)features which the framework(inettuts) provide !!

How to fix this conflict between ajax and jquery?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand well you search for the `noConflict()` command of jQuery

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/

You call it after you load the jQuery, and then you make your calls using the jQuery

Comment: no , I ask about the problem appear when i use update panel with jquery in the same time

Comment: @just_name Using this command you can avoid conflict. Try it.